# Puppeteer: page.click and page.evaluate click fallbacks

Tags: typescript, puppeteer

As title stated, most of the cases the page.click() works. However, sometimes, it clicks and the page doesn't react to the action. There two detailed scenarios:

1. The page.click() doesn't work and throw the error. In this case I can fall back to evaluate the click correctly.
2. The page.click() does work and it doesn't throw the error. The page doesn't react to the click. In this case, I don't know how to fall back to another click method.

There's a slight chance that evaluate click doesn't work as well. Therefore, I think the best solution is to fall back to each other when failing to click. Here is my code:

```
async clickElement(
    page: Page,
    projectName: string,
    title: string,
    selector: string,
    timeout = 1000,
    preventNavigation = false
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    Logger.log(selector, 'CSSClickStrategy.clickElement');

    // Ensure the selector is present before proceeding
    // it could be a navigation before awaiting the selector
    await Promise.race([
      page.waitForSelector(selector, { timeout, visible: true }),
      page.waitForNavigation({ timeout }),
    ]);
    //TODO: how to determine to switch between the two click methods
    // Add navigation prevention if required
    if (preventNavigation) {
      this.preventNavigationOnElement(page, selector);
      return this.evaluateClick(page, projectName, title, selector);
    } else {
      // const result = await this.normalClick(page, projectName, title, selector);
      const result = await this.evaluateClick(
        page,
        projectName,
        title,
        selector
      );
      if (!result) {
        // return await this.evaluateClick(page, projectName, title, selector);
        return await this.normalClick(page, projectName, title, selector);
      } else {
        return result;
      }
    }
  }

  private async preventNavigationOnElement(page: Page, selector: string) {
    await page.evaluate((sel) => {
      const element = document.querySelector(sel);
      if (element) {
        element.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.preventDefault());
      }
    }, selector);
  }

  private async evaluateClick(
    page: Page,
    projectName: string,
    title: string,
    selector: string,
    timeout = 10000
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      await Promise.race([
        page.evaluate((sel) => {
          const element = document.querySelector(sel) as HTMLElement;
          element?.click();
        }, selector),
        new Promise((_, reject) =>
          setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Timeout exceeded')), timeout)
        ),
      ]);
      Logger.log(
        `Clicked using page.evaluate for selector: ${selector}`,
        'CSSClickStrategy.clickElement'
      );
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.error(error.message, 'CSSClickStrategy.evaluateClick');
      return false;
    }
  }

  private async normalClick(
    page: Page,
    projectName: string,
    title: string,
    selector: string,
    timeout = 10000
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      await Promise.race([
        page.click(selector, { delay: 100 }),
        new Promise((_, reject) =>
          setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Timeout exceeded')), timeout)
        ),
      ]);
      Logger.log(
        `Clicked using page.click for selector: ${selector}`,
        'CSSClickStrategy.clickElement'
      );
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.error(error.message, 'CSSClickStrategy.clickElement');
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What error is `.click()` throwing for you? Can you share an actual site so the example is reproducible? Often times, there's no need to actually click an element to achieve an underlying result, so context of what the ultimate goal is is good to have. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen
Good question. It could be the timeout I set or any other unexpected errors, so I cannot really provide an example for it. However, the most important part is both clicks might not work as expected without throwing errors. I wrote an answer for more contexts and what I was trying to do. Let me know if you still have questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to fall back to each other based on some conditions. For example, I found most of the time the evaluate click would work but not on the third-party ecommerce payment gateway. Therefore, I use a page.click() on the payment page. Otherwise, use evaluate click by default. Another finding is that with one tab under the incognito context, the evaluate click doesn't work properly. Here is my solution code based on conditions and fallback to each other when bumped into errors:

```
async clickElement(
    page: Page,
    projectName: string,
    title: string,
    selector: string,
    timeout = 1000,
    preventNavigation = false
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    Logger.log(selector, 'CSSClickStrategy.clickElement');
    const domain = new URL(
      this.sharedService.getProjectDomain(projectName, {
        absolutePath: undefined,
        name: title,
      })
    ).hostname;

    // Ensure the selector is present and visible before proceeding
    await Promise.race([
      page.waitForSelector(selector, { timeout, visible: true }),
      page.waitForNavigation({ timeout }),
    ]);

    // Determine the click method based on conditions
    // only one page means checking datalayer; two pages mean checking with gtm preview mode
    // if the current page is not the same as the domain, then it's a third-party gateway
    const useNormalClick =
      (await page.browserContext().pages()).length === 1 ||
      !page.url().includes(domain);

    if (preventNavigation) {
      this.preventNavigationOnElement(page, selector);
    }

    if (useNormalClick) {
      return await this.attemptClick(
        page,
        projectName,
        title,
        selector,
        this.normalClick
      );
    } else {
      return await this.attemptClick(
        page,
        projectName,
        title,
        selector,
        this.evaluateClick
      );
    }
  }

  async attemptClick(
    page: Page,
    projectName: string,
    title: string,
    selector: string,
    clickMethod: (
      page: Page,
      projectName: string,
      title: string,
      selector: string
    ) => Promise<boolean>
  ) {
    const result = await clickMethod.call(
      this,
      page,
      projectName,
      title,
      selector
    );
    if (!result) {
      // Fallback to the other click method
      return await (clickMethod === this.normalClick
        ? this.evaluateClick
        : this.normalClick
      ).call(this, page, projectName, title, selector);
    }
    return result;
  }
 // other private methods are in the question content
```

Here is my launch setup for reference:

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: headless === 'new' ? 'new' : false,
      defaultViewport: null,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      args: [
        '--window-size=1440,900',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
        '--disable-gpu',
      ],
    });
```